# SVN in Intelli-J complaining: Outdated Version. Modified by xxx on

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am getting the following notifications in intelli J for a project versioned with SVN.

[image]

I have told the folder to update repeatedly but I am still getting the notifications. Additionally, even though the files seem to be updated to the latest version, I have errors that other people don't for the specific sub-module.

Any ideas how to fix this? I don't want to have to setup a completely new Intelli J project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around that didn't involve re-creating the whole project, but removing/re-adding the specific sub-module.

Steps

1. Delete the folder with the specific problematic versioning issue and sub-module.
2. Checkout the specific folder to another location ( or checkout the whole project in another folder).
3. Copy the new version of the folder back into the project.
4. Go to New> Module from Existing Sources ( and select the pom maven file)
5. Run `clean install -DskipTests`

The following steps fixed the problem for me.